# wget: unable to resolve host address ‘sudo’

Tags: sudo, dpkg, wget

I'm new to these stuffs so I am asking this question.
I'm trying to install Java v6 from terminal but I'm getting a couple of errors like:

`--2015-06-29 15:52:31-- http://sudo/
    Resolving sudo (sudo)... failed: Name or service not known.
    wget: unable to resolve host address ‘sudo’`

```
--2015-06-29 15:52:46--  http://dpkg
Resolving dpkg (dpkg)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘dpkg’

--2015-06-29 15:52:56--  http://!%3Carch%3E/
Resolving !<arch> (!<arch>)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘!<arch>’

--2015-06-29 15:53:11--  http://debian-binary%20%20%201399372320%20%200%20%20%20%20%200%20%20%20%20%20100644%20%204%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%60/
Resolving debian-binary   1399372320  0     0     100644  4         ` (debian-binary   1399372320  0     0     100644  4         `)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘debian-binary   1399372320  0     0     100644  4         `’

--2015-06-29 15:53:22--  http://2.0/
Resolving 2.0 (2.0)... 2.0.0.0
Connecting to 2.0 (2.0)|2.0.0.0|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

I'm trying to build a custom ROM for my device and it wants java v6 to be installed. So I went to a guide located at: http://forum.xda-developers.com/chef-central/android/guide-android-rom-development-t2814763 and I'm following it. And when I came to install java, this problem arrived.
Please help me out as soon as possible. My important work has been on stand-by. :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the exact command you ran to install Java 6. Don't forget to notify me by writing a comment containing "@ByteCommander" when you updated your post. Thank you!

Comment: @ByteCommander This was the command: wget https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java/+files/oracle-java6-installer_6u45-0%7Ewebupd8%7E8_all.deb sudo dpkg -i oracle-java6-installer_6u45-0~webupd8~8_all.deb wget https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java/+files/oracle-java6-set-default_6u45-0%7Ewebupd8%7E8_all.deb sudo dpkg -i oracle-java6-set-default_6u45-0~webupd8~8_all.deb

Comment: @PreetP. Please [edit] your question to add more information.

Comment: @muru I'm seriously unknown to all these things but I'll be in detail: I am building a custom ROM for my device, I have setup Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my windows 7 and replaced it with windows OS. And now, starting from scratch, I'm trying to install Java v6 which is supported by kitkat android version. I'm taking guide from this website: http://forum.xda-developers.com/chef-central/android/guide-android-rom-development-t2814763 Is this information okay? Or shall I go in more dept? Please tell me what should I include.

Comment: @PreetP. You really need to [edit] (<-- click this link!) your question to provide the command you used. And don't forget to use the **`{}`**-button for code-formatting. Otherwise some characters of your command might get lost during the markdown interpretation and it's extremely hard to read anyway.

Comment: @PreetP, Maybe you can read http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting --- a nicely formatted question attracts good answers. Need time, I know, but so do answering...

Comment: Unless you show us the command you used, we cannot determine why silly things are happening: `ht tp://sudo/`, `ht tp://dpkg/`,`ht ttp://!%3Carch%3E/`, etc. The space in "ht tp://" is in error, and site names like `sudo`, `dpkg`, `!%3Carch`, aside from being invalid, lead me to believe your command line is the problem.

Comment: Yes sir, I knew it (ht tp) and the problem is fixed already. I got my answer by Marc Vanhoomiseen below. And Java v6 is already installed on my PC. Thank you for the citation and I'll take care next time. Forgive me for my format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, the link you refer to should read:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java/+files/oracle-java6-installer_6u45-0%7Ewebupd8%7E8_all.deb 
sudo dpkg -i oracle-java6-installer_6u45-0~webupd8~8_all.deb 
wget https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java/+files/oracle-java6-set-default_6u45-0%7Ewebupd8%7E8_all.deb 
sudo dpkg -i oracle-java6-set-default_6u45-0~webupd8~8_all.deb
```

That is 4 commands to be typed in the terminal, not just one.  Basically, the first and third ones download a software while lines 2 and 4 install it.  Hope this helps.